# Code architecture opinion

Tags: architecture

I hall,

I need your opinion on what is best in the following case.

I have a hierarchic 2 level events class from a website (A and B are base class), this is coded in a framework dll (let's name it "TheLib.dll") to be factorized and reuseable:

A

- A son 1
- A son 2
- ...

B

- B son 1
- B son 2
- ...

Then I need some external tools (console/wpf app) that will display the content of each of this events each time wich some different (part of properties) and specific formatting for a log for exemple. But I get the event with their base type: A or B, not the native end type.

A first approach is to code this into "TheLibe.dll" declare an interface with a specific toStringxxx method and assign it to every events A son * and B son *

I am not fan of this, as the code should be in the console app and not into the framework because it will not be used in any other external tool.

So I coded the string formatting directly into the console app by using a generic cast from a call to GetType()

Let me know if it is good or bad and why ?

Sinn'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your console app can know about A and B and all the sub-types derived from them, there isn't really much wrong with using something like `GetType()` and doing your application specific formatting directly in the console app. Just understand this approach is not very scalable.

If however, A and B can continually be extended and your console app can never know about all the possible sub-types without rebuilding it, you are better off to provide either the `toString()` interface so each class can do its own formatting or a `print()` interface that you can pass some kind of output stream so you could format your output depending on the type of stream passed in (e.g. `ostream` derived class in C++, `java.io.OutputStream` derived class in Java, ...)

Comment: I am most in the second case, where A and B can be extended in the future. If a type is unknown in the console app I throw an exception and we then must code and rebuild, it is not very scalable but someone could also forget to implement the interface on a derived A or B type into the dll, which will also lead to an exception in the console app when it will encounter the derived type without the implemented tostring interface. So every 2 approach may lead to a problem. Maybe we then must do the scalable method, ethen if we code specific and 1 unique usage into the dll.